# Error: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info (React Native Amplify)

Tags: react-native, aws-lambda, expo, aws-amplify

I am using React Native Expo and AWS Amplify as the backend for my mobile application. Also, I am using lambda trigger functions along with my AWS Amplify backend.

After adding the lambda function, I cannot run my mobile application using **npm start**. Here is the error I got.

```
enter code hereError: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info
    at setModule (G:\GitProjFiles\React Native\ChatApp\ChatApp\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:620:17)
    at workerReply (G:\GitProjFiles\React Native\ChatApp\ChatApp\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:691:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 57)
```

I think the npm is detecting another `node_modules` folder that is related to my lambda function. Here is the file structure,

```
+-- .expo
+-- <b>node_modules</b>
|
+-- amplify
|   +-- backend
|      +-- function
|        +--function_name
|           +--src
|              <b>+--node_modules</b>
|              +--package.json
|              +--custom.js 
+-- src
|
+-- package.json
+-- yarn.lock
```

I did try deleting node_modules and re-installing, but the issue persists.

Comment: Did you solve it? Same thing happened to me, after adding amplify api and lambda functions my project no longer works. Very confusing.

Comment: No, I could not find a way to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I was using expo for my react-native mobile app.
My error message was:

```
Failed to construct transformer:  DuplicateError: Duplicated files or mocks. 
Please check the console for more info
at setModule (/home/arsen/Desktop/SignalClone/node_modules/jest-haste- 
map/build/index.js:543:17)
at workerReply (/home/arsen/Desktop/SignalClone/node_modules/jest-haste- 
map/build/index.js:614:9)
at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async Promise.all (index 29625)
at /home/arsen/Desktop/SignalClone/node_modules/jest-haste- 
map/build/index.js:426:22 {
mockPath1: 
'amplify/backend/function/SignalClonePostConfirmation/src/package.json',
mockPath2: 'amplify/#current-cloud- 
backend/function/SignalClonePostConfirmation/src/package.json'}
```

As you see in the error msg, there are two mockPaths (mockPath1 and mockPath2). So I simply deleted one of them(mockPath2) and the issue was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when working with expo monorepo. The issue was due to having two package.json files with the same name. You will have to change the name of one of the files.

You can change the name by going to the package.json file and then updating the property name.

The error gives the path the the package.json files

[image]